# Sikuli with jenkins setup for continuous integration

Tags: sikuli

I have my test writtern in Sikuli. If I RDP into my Jenkins machine and have an active session then all sikuli test pass.

However, for overnight run, my Jenkins machine do get locked. I want to understand if anyone has encountered and solved this issue before. Thanks!

Note: I cannot leave my Jenkins slave unlocked due to security reasons.

Comment: Can we assume that the tests are not successful when the machine is locked and accessed using RDP? Is this your problem?

Comment: Yes,tests are not successful when the machine is locked! However, when I launch an RDP session and connect to Jenkins slave and kick off test- then the tests are successful. However, for overnight runs, I cannot do this. I cannot create an active session by logging into RDP.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known limitation of RDP.
Two optional solutions:

1. install VNC Server (like **[UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/downloads.html)**), and run it as Windows service (make sure it is launched during Windows logon).

OR

2. Create a batch file that disconnects Remote Desktop, and use it instead of closing the RDP session with the regular X button. The batch command is:

   **%windir%\system32\tscon.exe %SESSIONNAME% /dest:console**